# Saving a copy of a fragment in a stack for revert the status

Tags: android, android-fragments

I developed a game inside a fragment. Many views are involved and even more variables. Now I need a revert-button and I thought about to save the hole fragment in a stack and when the revert button is pressed I only pop the last fragment and replace it.

My problem is that any fragment in this stack is updated since something happens in the userinterface. However, I need the state of the past where the fragment was saved. So it should be freezed or something? So how can I make an actual copy and not a duplicate which is updated.

**saving method**

```
Fragment fragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.container);
MainActivity.fragmentStack.push(fragment);
```

**loading method**

```
Fragment fragment = MainActivity.fragmentStack.pop();
ActionBarActivity ac = (ActionBarActivity) root.getContext();
FragmentManager fragmentManager = ac.getSupportFragmentManager();
fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.container, fragment)
                        .commit();
```

P.s.: Of course I could store all single variables anywhere at build a new fragment with the stored values. However, I want to store the whole in fragment in one step.

Comment: So what prevents you from making a deep copy of your fragment? Add a constructor in your class that takes another fragment as an argument, creates copies of all of its reference variables, etc. But if you want a real solution than the first answer is pretty much a way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fragment is a heavy class with lifecycles that have to be consistent. You do not want to save and manage that.

Instead what you should do is create a class that holds that state and make it [parcelable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html). Then have a fragment use that object to set itself up. By making it parcelable it can also save that object in the saved instance state which will make recreating the fragment and it's views much simpler.

Comment: You actually mean with state any single variable I set up? Or I cannot follow your idea

Comment: A fragment is supposed to show views based on the state of your app. So you need to pass that state into the fragment in some manner. Remember that fragments and activities can be destroyed during things like phone orientation changes which is why I was suggesting you save that state in the saved instance state.

Comment: Yes. I wanted to ask if the "state" how you call it is something specific like a single object which I can save or do you mean with state the combination of any variables which describe the state?

Comment: So by the design of android and how fragments should be implemented, any fragment should be able to re-create its state based on the current situation of the app (due to the fact that they can be destroyed when the app is backgrounded during a phone call or orientation changes). Since the fragments need to be able to restore state anyway, you need to control that when you set the fragment up by passing its state into the args most likely